find if filename contains a certain (article number) string
I am currently uploading images directly to wordpress. The file names of the images also contain the article number in the form
arm-1001-01.jpg
arm-1001-02.jpg
arm-1001-03.jpg
arm-1001-04.jpg

arm-1002-01.jpg
arm-1002-02.jpg

arm-1003-01.jpg
arm-1003-02.jpg
arm-1003-03.jpg

Now the idea would be to use the following code to automatically assign the images to the products. The code works only for one image with exactly the filename/product sku matching. So how is it possible to get all the matching images for an product, to find if filename of image contains a certain (article number) string.
Product 1 has sku "arm-1001", product 2 has sku "arm-1002" and so on.
    add_action('add_attachment', function( $attachmentID ) {
  if ( ! class_exists( 'WC_Product' ) ) return; // if no WooCommerce do nothing

  // an attachment was jus saved, first of all get the file name
  $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachmentID, 'full' );
  $filename = pathinfo( $src[0], PATHINFO_FILENAME );

  // now let's see if exits a product with the sku that match filename
  $args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_sku',
    'meta_value' => $filename,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => '1' // assuming sku is unique get only one post
  );
  $prods = get_posts( $args );
  if ( ! empty($prods) ) {

    // ok we have a match, exists a product having sku that match filename
    $product = array_pop( $prods );

    // set the thumbnail for the product
    set_post_thumbnail( $product, $attachmentID );

    // now "attach" the post to the product setting 'post_parent'
    $attachment = get_post( $attachmentID );
    $attachment->post_parent = $product->ID;
    wp_update_post( $attachment );
  }
});

PS: It would probably be even more elegant to use the plugin's API. Then you could probably also do without the synchronization using file names.
Here is a screenshot of the "logical" arrangement of the Wordpress plugin.
Screenshot Media Organizer
Based on the screenshot example, I would like to assign the images of collection "ARM-1002" to the product with the article number "ARM-1002".
"ARM-1002-60" is the sub-product, so the collection is named "ARM-1002-60-ROT".
And I would like to proceed in the same way with all other products/pictures.
This would be my preferred way, then I could possibly do without the assignment using image file names

Do you want to find all the files in a specific directory? Then you can use a glob pattern.

Yes, I would like to retrieve the images from a specific directory. Basically, the images are all physically located in one media directory: wp-content/uploads/
I use the Wordpress plugin WP/LR Sync to upload images directly from Adobe Lightroom to Wordpress. The images are logically created in "collections" that mirror the Lightroom folder structure.
Now I would like to try to use the plugin's API to assign the images to the individual products. According to the API, you can access the collections/folders.

Relevant: PHP preg_split: Split string by hyphen and PHP: How to get a string from between the first two occurences of character

Also relevant: Glob pattern matching the first part of a file name and PHP Get file name starting with prefix

You want to extract the SKU from the filename string?
$filename  = "arm-1001-01.jpg";
$arr = explode("-", $filename);
$sku = $arr[0] . '-' . $arr[1];

// now let's see if exits a product with the sku that match filename
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => '_sku',
    'meta_value' => $sku,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => '1' // assuming sku is unique get only one post
);
$prods = get_posts( $args );

